# Java - RMI - Client/Server

Tags: java, rmi

I have completed a program with multiple methods in the Server class. I have an interface which is implemented by the Server class and a client which calls the methods, I keep getting the no connection to local host error when I try to run the server class.

So basically my question is, what is the best way to go about adding a client & server to an already completed program. The program includes database connection and I am using netbeans. I have tried various tutorials and examples, and I get the same result. It's going to happen on the same computer, no real networking happening.

What am I missing?! 
A step by step explanation on how this works would be great, the various sources online are different to one another and mostly go on about chat clients. My program is in a nutshell - does database search,add and remove. I have atleast 10 methods in the program. I can see this question may be quite vague but any good up to date resources on learning this would be helpful too.

Other info:
Server class - has all the methods regarding database and tablemodels

adminGUI class - has it's own panel set methods for gui design and action listeners for the swing components, which call the methods from the Server class

usergUI class - same as adminGUI

InterfaceClass - Declares all the methods from the server class and throws remote exception

Thanks in advance, please let me know if any code is required, I have removed all RMI related code now as I want to start fresh, the only thing remaining is the interfaceclass to start.

Comment: Add some sample code and complete stack trace.

Comment: I no longer have the RMI code, but I got this result : java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.0.4; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Do you have the registry running?

Comment: I am not sure, am completely new to this. How would I check this?

Comment: If you don't know that you have it running, you don't have it running. See the Javadoc.